# How to convert type-level list into chain of pairs

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, singleton-type

The singletons library seems too difficult to deal with it without strong background. Is there any way to convert level typed list like `'[1, 2, 3]` into chain of pairs like `'(1, '(2, '(3, '())))`?

I've tried to write few lines but they produce expressionless for me errors.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeInType #-}

module ExpandList where

import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.Tuple

type family IntoChainOfPairs (xs :: [k]) :: (k, b) where
  IntoChainOfPairs (x ': '[]) = '(x, '())
  IntoChainOfPairs (x ': xs) = '(x, IntoChainOfPairs xs)

sIntoChainOfPairs :: forall a (t :: [a]). Sing t -> Sing (IntoChainOfPairs t)
sIntoChainOfPairs = \case
  SCons a SNil -> STuple2 a STuple0
  SCons a b -> STuple2 a (sIntoChainOfPairs b)
```

So I stacked in fundamental misunderstanding. Compiler doesn't understand me, I don't understand it. I'm sure my code is wrong at the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `IntoChainOfPairs`'s result should change with the input. Therefore, there are actually two functions, one `type ToPairsType (xs :: [a]) :: Type`—computing the output type from the input—and one `type ToPairs (xs :: [a]) :: ToPairsType xs`—actually computing the output.

```
type family ToPairsType (xs :: [a]) :: Type where
  ToPairsType '[] = ()
  ToPairsType ((_ :: a) : xs) = (a, ToPairsType xs)
type family ToPairs (xs :: [a]) :: ToPairsType xs where
  ToPairs '[] = '()
  ToPairs (x : xs) = '(x, ToPairs xs)
```

You defined a single partial function, where `b` was an argument to `IntoChainOfPairs`. You really wrote

```
type family IntoChainOfPairs (k :: Type) (b :: Type) (xs :: [k]) :: (k, b) where
  IntoChainOfPairs k () (x : '[]) = '(x, '())
  IntoChainOfPairs k (k, b') (x : xs) = '(x, IntoChainOfPairs k b' xs)
```

Where you had partial pattern matching on `b`, with nonlinear matching on `k`. Additionally, the unnatural (partial!) list-processing does not help. You can sorta-maybe-painfully get value-level `case` on `Type`s, using the `Typeable` infrastructure, for writing `sIntoChainOfPairs`, but I would not advise it. Really, `IntoChainOfPairs` is just broken.

`sToPairs` is written as a direct "reflection" of `ToPairs`:

```
sToPairs :: forall (a :: Type) (xs :: [a]). Sing xs -> Sing (ToPairs xs)
sToPairs SNil = STuple0
sToPairs (SCons x xs) = STuple2 x (sToPairs xs)
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be the _kind_ rather than the _type_ which changes with the input?

Comment: @bradrn In Haskell, types have types. Due to historical reasons, the type of a type is often called its kind. I prefer to pretend the word "kind" doesn't exist, until someone else brings it up, because it was a deliberate move to eliminate the distinction from the language.

Comment: @HTNW, amazing! This pattern of splitting computation into 2 steps is everywhere in singletons, and now I'm starting to understand why it's used. Thanks!